# MySQL devuelve "#1054 - La columna 'persona.tipo' en on clause es desconocida"

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Tengo esta sentencia:

```
SELECT registro_vehiculo.fecha_entrada, persona.nombre,tipo_servicio.tipo_servicio

FROM registro_vehiculo,persona,tipo_servicio 
INNER JOIN tipo_persona ON tipo_persona.id_tipop=persona.tipo 
WHERE registro_vehiculo.fecha_entrada >= '2017-01-01' 
AND registro_vehiculo.fecha_entrada <='2017-04-20' 
ORDER BY registro_vehiculo.fecha_entrada ASC
```

y me marca este error

> MySQL ha dicho:
>
> #1054 - La columna 'persona.tipo' en on clause es desconocida

¿Alguien sabe el porqué del error?

La estructura de mi tabla "persona" es esta:

```
create table persona (
      id_persona int not null, 
      tipo int not null, 
      nombre varchar (20) not null,
      apellidos varchar (30) not null,
      telefono char(15) not null,
      direccion varchar (25) not null,
      correo varchar (30) not null,
      rfc varchar (20)not null, 
      primary key(id_persona),
      index pers_tipo(tipo),
      foreign key (tipo) references tipo_persona(id_tipop));
```

y la de la tabla "tipo_persona" es:

```
create table tipo_persona (
             id_tipop int, 
             primary key(id_tipop) , 
             tipo_persona varchar(10) not null);
```

Como verán, sí tengo llave foránea en mi tabla "persona".

Comment: En mi tabla persona tengo la llave foránea reverenciada a mi tabla tipo_persona por eso los caso ahí

Comment: Más allá del error, te das cuenta que estás haciendo al menos 2 productos cartesianos?

Comment: _If there are two or more tables listed in the MySQL FROM clause, these tables are generally joined using INNER or OUTER joins, as opposed to the older syntax in the WHERE clause._ Es extraño que tu tabla `registro_vehiculo` no aparezca en el `JOIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar la posición de la tabla `Personas` en el From, para que la tabla sobre la que haces el **join** sea la correcta y se pueda aplicar la condición. Ya que en tu caso estás haciendo el **join** sobre la tabla `tipo_servicio`.

Tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT registro_vehiculo.fecha_entrada,
     persona.nombre,
     tipo_servicio.tipo_servicio    
FROM registro_vehiculo,
     tipo_servicio,
     persona 
     INNER JOIN tipo_persona 
     ON tipo_persona.id_tipop=persona.tipo 
WHERE registro_vehiculo.fecha_entrada >= '2017-01-01' 
AND registro_vehiculo.fecha_entrada <='2017-04-20' 
ORDER BY registro_vehiculo.fecha_entrada ASC
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! eso resolvió mi problema

Answer (score 2):

Esto tiene pinta de problema en el orden de operadores. 
Creo que el problema es en el from de la consulta:

```
FROM registro_vehiculo,tipo_servicio , persona
INNER JOIN tipo_persona ON tipo_persona.id_tipop=persona.tipo
```

El inner join relaciona una tabla con la siguiente. En la consulta original esta intentando relacionar tipo_servicio con tipo persona (por eso el error). Cambia el orden de las tablas.
.